# MATLAB - How to plot the boundary of a face?

Tags: matlab, image-segmentation

I've been working with MATLAB for a couple of weeks now. But I am having trouble getting an accurate inner boundary of an input face image.

My code involves using Haar cascades to get the box around the face and the nose. Then I use the mid point of the nose box as the tip of the nose `[nx, ny]`. From then on, I try to get the boundary of the face by:

- Converting it to gray scale
- Increasing the contrast
- Plotting the "Active Countour" of the face by searching only in the box bounded by the mask of range `[rows, cols]` plotted in blue. This active contour gives a rough image around the face
- Since The boundary started going outside the face, I thought I needed to "erode" the image with `imerode`. This is followed by `bwboundaries`. I also commented out the alternative of using `bwmorph` and `bwtraceboundaries`.
- `imgradient, imfilter` may be unnecessary, but I was playing around with it to see how everything would play out. When the boundary came inside the face, I thought of dialating the image with `imdilate`. I don't know if it is common practice to do so, but the boundary is mehh, but **very ugly**.

Here is the original image (without markers) : http://images.wisegeek.com/passport-photo.jpg

Here is the ungly bordered image:

[image]

The code that powers this :

```
    clear all;

    %Crop face part from Haar
    I = imread('images/photo_1.jpg');
    I = imresize(I,0.3);


    face_detector = vision.CascadeObjectDetector;
    nose_detector = vision.CascadeObjectDetector('Nose');

    face_detector.MergeThreshold = 4;
    nose_detector.MergeThreshold = 20; 

    fbox = step(face_detector, I); %holds coords of boxed image
    nbox = step(nose_detector, I); %holds coords of boxed image

    %find center of nose Haar box
    nx = nbox(1) + nbox(3)/2;
    ny = nbox(2) + nbox(4)/2;

    %out = insertObjectAnnotation(I, 'rectangle',fbox, 'face', 'Color','cyan');

    imshow(I);
    hold on;
    title('Original Image');

    %plot tip of nose
    plot(nx,ny, 'Marker','+','Color','red','MarkerSize',10);

    factor = 20; %number of px before and after Haar boundary
    rows = fbox(2)-factor:fbox(2)+fbox(4)+factor;
    cols = fbox(1)-factor:fbox(1)+fbox(3)+factor;

    %% Plot mask

    mask = false(size(I(:,:,1)));
    mask(rows, cols) = true;
    visboundaries(mask, 'Color','b');

    %%
    I_gray = rgb2gray(I);
    I_contrast = imadjust(I_gray);

    f = fspecial('disk',1);
    I_filtered = imfilter(I_contrast, f);


    [Gmag, Gdir] = imgradient(I_filtered,'prewitt');
    bw1 = activecontour(Gmag, mask, 600, 'edge');

    se = strel('disk',15);
    small_bw1 = imerode(bw1, true(60));
    small_bw1 = imdilate(small_bw1,se);
    small_boundary = bwboundaries(small_bw1);
    % small_bw1 = bwmorph(bw1, 'thin', Inf);
    % small_boundary = bwboundaries(small_bw1);

    visboundaries(small_bw1,'Color','r');
    title('Final is in red');

    figure;
    imshow(bw1), title('bw1');

    %% Get Coordinates of face boundary

    figure;
    [B, L] = bwboundaries(bw1, 'noholes');
    imshow(label2rgb(L, @jet, [.5 .5 .5]));
    hold on;
    for k = 1:length(B)
        boundary = B{k};
        plot(boundary(:,2), boundary(:,1), 'w', 'LineWidth', 2);
    end;
```

Here are some sample images I am working with :

- http://images.wisegeek.com/passport-photo.jpg
- http://thispix.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/passport-001.jpg
- http://www.srednja.hr/Photos/moda/makeup-for-life-phyllis-passport-picture.jpg
- http://www.naourmarket.com/public/img/agent_photos/passport2.jpg

The ultimate objective is to draw a perfect boundary around the face, but **without** the hair. Only the skin part from his/her chin to her forehead should be enclosed in the boundary. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you also provide the original image (without the drawings on it)?

Comment: Here is the one I used in the question : http://images.wisegeek.com/passport-photo.jpg. I have also included more in the updated answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I extended your code to detect the face as shown below.

- I started from the detection of nose and eyes using the `CascadeObjectDetector`. I extended these regions to include the mouth and eyebrows, respectively. These regions are forced to be part of the final face region.
- The detection of the face boundary is done by thresholding the second order derivatives of the gray scale image. Especially the chin is hard to detect correctly. The border between the chin and the neck is highlighted by applying a large erosion step. Because this step is sensitive to noise in the face region, the image is first filtered non linearly by applying a small dilation and erosion step.
- The face region is determined using the eroded image, otherwise the boundary between the chin and the neck may not be clear. Afterwards, the large erosion is undone by applying the (inverse) dilation step.
- The results are quite good for the simple approach, but not perfect. You may obtain better results by iteratively changing the threshold used for the second order derivatives. If you start from a large threshold the neck will be included in the face region. You can detect it by assuming some maximum distance between the nose region and the bottom of the face. Then, you can decrease the threshold until the neck is not included anymore. Another alternative to make this method more robust may be to normalise the LoG.

[image: Face detection method applied to the sample face of the OP.]

---

```
clear all;
close all;

I = imread('passport-001.jpg');
I = imresize(I,240/size(I, 1)); % resize all the images to the same size

nose_detector = vision.CascadeObjectDetector('Nose');
eye_detector = vision.CascadeObjectDetector('EyePairSmall');   

nose_detector.MergeThreshold = 20; 

nbox = step(nose_detector, I); % box around the nose
nbox = nbox(1,:); % guess the first box is correct
% extend the box to include the mouth
nbox(1) = nbox(1) - 0.1*nbox(3);
nbox(3) = 1.2*nbox(3);
nbox(4) = 1.5*nbox(4);

ebox = step(eye_detector, I); % box around the eyes
% extend the eye box to include the eyebrows
ebox(2) = ebox(2) - 0.5*ebox(4);
ebox(4) = 1.5*ebox(4);

%find center of nose Haar box
nx = nbox(1) + nbox(3)/2;
ny = nbox(2) + nbox(4)/2;

% plot the original image
figure
subplot(2,3,1);
imshow(I);
hold on;
title('Original Image');

% indicate the nose (with mouth) and eye regions
rectangle('Position',nbox,'EdgeColor', 'r')
rectangle('Position',ebox,'EdgeColor', 'r')

% create a filter for the detected parts of the face (eye, mouth and nose)
maskFilter = uint8(ones(size(I(:,:,1))));
maskFilter(nbox(2):(nbox(2)+nbox(4)), nbox(1):(nbox(1)+nbox(3))) = 0;
maskFilter(ebox(2):(ebox(2)+ebox(4)), ebox(1):(ebox(1)+ebox(3))) = 0;

% convert to grayscale
I_gray = rgb2gray(I);
% filter high frequency noise
I_gray = imfilter(I_gray, fspecial('gaussian', [3,3], 0.5));

% plot the filtered grayscale image
subplot(2,3,2); imshow(I_gray);
title('Gray');

% calculate second order derivatives (laplacian of gaussians)
f = fspecial('log',[5 5], 0.3);
I_filtered = imfilter(I_gray, f);
I_filtered = I_filtered.*maskFilter; % exclude the detected parts of the face

% plot the laplacian of gaussians
subplot(2,3,3); imshow(I_filtered);
title('LoG');

% apply thresshold to LoG
I_bin = I_filtered < 40;
seDiskNoise = strel('disk',1);
seDiskClose = strel('disk',10);
I_bin1 = imerode(imdilate(I_bin,seDiskNoise), seDiskNoise); % remove noise from the face
I_bin2 = imerode(I_bin1,seDiskClose); % close the boundaries of the face
I_bin3 = imdilate(I_bin2,seDiskClose); % reverse the erode (not used for processing)

subplot(2,3,4); imshow(I_bin1); title('LoG > 50');
subplot(2,3,5); imshow(I_bin2); title('eroded');
subplot(2,3,6); imshow(I_bin3); title('dilated');

CC = bwconncomp(I_bin2); % calculate the regions in the binary image

% search the region containing the nose
ni = sub2ind(size(I_gray), round(ny), round(nx));
for i=1:length(CC.PixelIdxList)
  if any(CC.PixelIdxList{i}==ni)
    iPhase = i;
  end
end

% create a mask for the full face
maskFace = zeros(size(I_gray));
maskFace(CC.PixelIdxList{iPhase}) = 1;
% undo the erosion
maskFace = imdilate(maskFace, seDiskClose);

% visualise the face region
subplot(2,3,1);
visboundaries(maskFace,'Color','b');

% remove all the extrusions and inner regions of the face region
seDisk2 = strel('disk',20);
maskFace = imerode(imdilate(maskFace, seDisk2), seDisk2);

% draw the final face region in red
subplot(2,3,1);
visboundaries(maskFace,'Color','r');
title('Final is in red');
```

[image: Face detection method applied to a second sample face]

Comment: Cool !  But I noticed that the "Final in Red" boundary is not accurate for http://www.naourmarket.com/public/img/agent_photos/passport2.jpg . it even goes a tad out of his head. Is there any way to deal with that?

Comment: The tad out of his had was due to end effects of the last erosion and dilation step `maskFace = imerode(imdilate(maskFace, seDisk2), seDisk2);` I decreased the disk radius from 40 to 20. As an alternative, you may add extra pixels around the image when performing this last step, because the problem occurs when the dilation step reaches the border of the image. Note that the beard and the non-homogeneous lighting of the face makes the processing much more difficult.

Comment: Thought so. Plainer the image is, the better. Thanks!